# Activity.findViewById returning null sporadically

Tags: android

From the crash logs that I am getting from the Android market, I can see
that some of my users are getting Force Closes caused by
NullPointerExceptions when my code tries to access views that are in my
application.  In one example, my activity makes a call to findViewById()
in onCreate() after I call setContentView().  I get an NPE when I try to
access the view after the call to findViewById() (still in onCreate).
What has me really scratching my head is that this does not happen all
of the time (in fact most of the time the code acts as I would expect),
but enough to have me concerned.

I could add code to *always* check for null and avoid the NPE, but I
would like to understand what could be causing the sporadic behavior.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: please submit onCreate on xml code

Answer (score 0):

Rename that view may be you can find the view as expected.